# CRUD storage pattern Infinite gas error when trying to implement in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, storage

I'm trying to implement @robhitchens CRUD storage pattern in solidity, and I'm getting infinate gas costs when I import the library. Not sure where to go from here.

one of them:

Gas requirement of function HitchensUnorderedKeySet.exists(bytes32) high: infinite. 
If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

import "https://github.com/rob-Hitchens/UnorderedKeySet/blob/master/contracts/HitchensUnorderedKeySet.sol";

contract Filter {

    using HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib for HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib.Set;
    HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib.Set filterSet;

    struct FilterStruct {
        string name;
        string tag;
    }


    mapping(bytes32 => FilterStruct) public filters;

    event LogNewFilter(address sender, bytes32 key, string Filternamename);

    function newFilter(bytes32 key, string memory name) public {
        filterSet.insert(key);
        FilterStruct storage f = filters[key];
        f.name = name;


        emit LogNewFilter(msg.sender, key, name);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This "warning" relates to the 'require' conditions that may not be 'true'. It can be safely ignored. Experiment with 'require' in a simple setting to see what I mean.

Hopefully the Remix team will find a way to make the warning more useful, with fewer false positives.

Hope it helps.

P.s. You can silence the high/infinite gas warning in Remix.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks very much for your help. When I deploy the contract in remix no functions appear to interact with, any idea why this is? Based on your response it seems unrelated to the unlimited gas warning.

Comment: seems to be stuck on "creation of Filter pending..."

Comment: From just eyeballing your contract, I don't think it's related to the contract either. Make sure you are using the JavaScript VM and not Injected Web3 unless you know what you are doing. I think it is waiting for a response from a non-existant node.

Comment: Using JavaScript VM, tried both Http and Https remix addresses, and different browsers. the contract and the imported contracts wont deploy, all just hang on "pending.."

Comment: I replicated it. I suspect there are multiple quirks with Remix today. Change this line to take github out of the picture (copy local, always a good idea). `import "./HitchensUnorderedKeySet.sol";`, then comment out the `nukeset()` function from the library. I found the problem persists if either of those steps isn't taken. I know of no reason why either step should be necessary but the IDE is updated frequently and stuff happens from time to time.